# reading from xml file into datatable and grid view

Tags: c#, xml

my xml is like below

```
<Expression>
    <Field>X</Field>
    <Formula>a+b</Formula>          
</Expression>
<Expression>
    <Field>Y</Field>
    <Formula>a-b</Formula>          
</Expression>
<Expression>
    <Field>Z</Field>
    <Formula>a*b</Formula>          
</Expression>
```

my c# page

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();           
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\\Test.xml");
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].ToString();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

it keeps showing me error:

> There are multiple root elements. Line 6, position 4.

Comment: Add a general root out of the expression elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xml file [must have single root element](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), which have other elements as children. Currently you have several `Expression` elements on root level. Wrap them into some `Expressions` element to make your xml file valid:

```
<Expressions>
  <Expression>
    <Field>X</Field>
    <Formula>a+b</Formula>
  </Expression>
  <Expression>
    <Field>Y</Field>
    <Formula>a-b</Formula>
  </Expression>
  <Expression>
    <Field>Z</Field>
    <Formula>a*b</Formula>
  </Expression>
</Expressions>
```

Your xml loading code is valid. It creates DataSet with single DataTable named *Expression*. That table has two columns (*Field* and *Formula*) and three rows with data.